# C program - Segmentation Fault - popen: Too many open files - sh: 0: Pipe call failed

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, popen

My C program crashs after running for 1h30. I get a "segmentation fault".
I debug though gdb and there is my error:

```
sh: 0: Pipe call failed
popen: Too many open files
```

I checked my code and for all popen command, I put pclose, idem for open/close.
But, I still get the same behaviour.

What can I do?
Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Comment: After an hour and 30 minutes? Best guess is that you *haven't* completely balanced every open/close as you think, but a guess is all that can be given without any code to see. However, is the error "too many open files" or is it "segmentation fault"? Are you *checking* that each file was successfully opened, or just hoping?

Comment: `sh: 0: Pipe call failed` Are you executing command from your program ?

Answer (score 2):

> I checked my code and for all popen command, I put pclose, idem for open/close.

These are far from the only calls which open file descriptors. Some of the others are `dup`, `pipe`, `socket`, etc.

> What can I do?

Run your program under `strace -e file ...` -- if `open`s keep returning higher and higher file descriptors, you definitely have a file descriptor leak, and looking at `strace` output should allow you to guess where it's happening.